# im trying to conveniently download responses in the DevTools Network tab?

Tags: json, http, http-headers, httpresponse, devtools

I'm wondering if there's a browser extension that adds a convenient download icon next to each network response in the DevTools Network tab, allowing me to easily download the response content.

If such an extension exists, could you please provide its name or any relevant details? If not, is there a recommended approach or script to achieve this functionality?

I appreciate any insights or recommendations on this matter. Thank you!

i looked it up in the store but all extensions deal mostly with requests and there no function to download responses.